# Testing Library's userEvent.click doesn't work

Tags: next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I developed a project with NextJS. I want to test the pathname of the link in the navbar using Jest and Testing Library but userEvent.click doesn't work. So either the pathname doesn't change, it keeps returning / or userEvent.click doesn't work. How to fix that problem?

***Navbar.tsx Component***

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import React from 'react';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Link href="/" className="text-3xl font-deca font-extrabold italic" data-testid="logo">
        AvaDronity
      </Link>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link href="/drones">drones</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/cameras">cameras</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/robots">robots</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/explore">explore</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/support">support</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

***Navbar.test.tsx File***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

describe('Navbar Component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<Navbar />);
  });

  it('should redirect to url and update history', async () => {
    const {
      location: { pathname },
    } = createMemoryHistory();
    console.log(pathname);

    const user = userEvent.setup();
    await user.click(screen.getByText('drones', { exact: false }));

    console.log(pathname);

    expect(pathname).toEqual('/drones');
  });
});
```

I've reviewed and tried similar errors and questions from different web sites, but I couldn't get any results.

In the test I wrote, pathname should be updated to /drones as expected after the userEvent.click event.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but was able to overcome it with `fireEvent` for the Next Link component specifically. So in theory, the following code should work for you --

```
fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('drones', { exact: false }));
```

While knowing that `userEvent` is a preferred way to simulate user interaction, I wasn't able to find any other ways to get it working and fell back to `fireEvent` as the last resort.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering if you can take a look on this. I've similar problem, but I can't solve it neither by the `fireEvent` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77442805/userevent-click-doesnt-trigger-expected-changes-on-this-unit-test