# "userEvent.click" doesn't trigger expected changes on this unit test

Tags: react-testing-library, primereact

I have this [simple example](https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-dropdowns-panel-width-yp9v59?file=/tests/dropdown.test.js) where I'm trying to write a test for component containing Primereact Dropdown. But even the mouse click shows the panel with options, I can't get options in my test.

For quick review, I'm placing the test here as well:

```
import {
  render,
  act,
  fireEvent,
  waitFor,
  screen
} from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import GroupedDemo from "../src/App";

describe("Test App Component", () => {
  it("Primereact dropdown", async () => {
    const { container } = render(<GroupedDemo />);
    await userEvent.click(screen.getAllByText("Select a City")[1]);
    expect(container.querySelector(".p-dropdown-panel")).not.toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Try `await waitFor(()=>userEvent.click(screen.getAllByText("Select a City")[1]))`, or `await waitFor(()=>expect(container.querySelector(".p-dropdown-panel")).not.toBeNull() )`

Comment: Is there a more than one "Select a City" dropdown? Felt a bit strange since you are getting the second element from your getAllByText query. Just wanted to be sure that it is not a indexing issue

Comment: There is hidden `select` element returned by the `getAllByText` as well. That element is organized by the Primereact due to accessibility. Therefore I'm accessing second one, what is visible in the browser and I want to interact with in my test.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to play with `waitFor`, but not specifically your suggestion @i2i3. I left it in the codebox, but it doesn't pass still.

Comment: Can you try using `userEvent.selectOptions(getByTestId('select'), '<value>');`?

Comment: That was nice try, but unfortunately it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some time spent deeper with it and react testing library documentation I came up with this repository where I have set of simple unit tests to confirm UX functionality.

[github.com/dominikj111/UXConfirmationTests](https://github.com/dominikj111/UXConfirmationTests)

Surely, I didn't know how to use the tool before, but I'm going to comment those mentioned here.

- `waitFor` is for to wait for your expectations to pass ([doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)).
- Sometimes we need to wait for an element what disappearing because of fading animation ([doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitforelementtoberemoved)).
- The other problem I had was misunderstanding the returned value of [the queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about).
- For some reason, I can't inspect the DOM from the container returned by the render method, ([please, see this in doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro#the-problem))(this is something I'm going to investigate in near future again). Anyway, to debug your test and see the DOM structure, [check this out](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/). Something like this `screen.queryByText("Group 1").parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("[role='checkbox']")` works well. `getByRole` doesn't work :-( (I'll need to review this as well)

This fixed test in the example of my question above works well:

```
  render(<GroupedDemo />);

  expect(screen.queryByText("Chicago")).toBeNull();
  expect(screen.queryByText("Los Angeles")).toBeNull();

  fireEvent.click(screen.getAllByText("Select a City")[1]);

  expect(screen.queryByText("Chicago")).not.toBeNull();
  expect(screen.queryByText("Los Angeles")).not.toBeNull();
```